# Dumbledore - Saint or Sinner?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

Now, this isn't intended to spark a monstrous debate, but I think that JK Rowlings writing of Dumbledore was a not only genius, but was geared towards seeing how it could be portrayed in different media e.g film and television, long before the films were created.

Harris was the original, but Gambon will be always be remembered as this iconic character, but was his treatment of Harry barbaric, or caring? Or necessary? Or correct?

All opinions welcome, just wanna see how this now iconic character changed from Jo Rowling’s pen to the silver screen via the two legendary actors who played him, and who would like to see a Dumbledore Prequel, with Ariana, Aberforth, Grindelwald et al! Wouldn't that be something, even as a novel or a film. Surely he has a story to rival even Harry's. His 'quest for power' as Aberforth puts it in Deathly Hallows! What a movie that would make following *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*. Just some opinions guys so be gentle but bring everything on!

Comment: I worry that this question might be purely opinion-based. I won't downvote, but you almost certainly will get a lot. Typically we like questions that are moderately objective, as opposed to soliciting people's personal opinions.

Comment: Yes, this seems like it’s only asking for opinions, which would be off-topic for the site.

Comment: You have a site which is based upon asking questions, yet you dislike asking for opinions? Surely a contradiction in terms? What is media and  literature if not to formulate opinions? Harry Potter is a fictional story , therefore the only way to interpret it is to form an opinion and then comment upon that opinion surely? How else would you base an argument or any other form of conversation?

Comment: Basically, it should not be a question that is *just* an opinion. "Was Dumbledore a Dark Wizard?" would probably be fine, as would "Did Dumbledore care about Harry"?  Literary interpretation is fun, but not necessarily on topic. "Was Dumbledore Christian?" Good. "Was Dumbledore a good Christian?" Not so good.

Comment: Ok fair enough, but surely by asking an ambiguous question I am tailoring said question to receive a wider range of responses? Your question is a simple yes or no based in 'opinion' of what you've read, whereas mine allows for judgement and a more rounded argument. Surely that's better than 'did he care about Harry' or have I missed the point of a debate!

Comment: You haven't missed the point of a debate, nor is your question "bad."  The thing is, this isn't really a debate. Basically, we want people to ask a question, and get an answer that is somewhat objective. Not all question are yes/no, either: for example, "Why did Dumbledore hire Lockhart?" Some opinion or extrapolation may be needed, but answers should be something people are likely to have some agreement on. We do have room for opinionated debates though: there are various chat rooms in which there are no (well, few) restrictions on the format of topics.

Comment: Right ok I understand the point you're making. It does disappoint me though that such literary debate should be saved for aimless chat rooms rather than on multimedia such as this site but ok point taken. Questions seeking seeemigly factual (according to canon) answers will be more of the order than the last one. No worries guys.

Comment: Unfortunately, ambiguity is precisely one of the things we are not looking for in questions. It is great for essay prompts but here it: (a) tends to attract low-quality answers, (b) tends to lead to heated arguments, (c) often will not be useful to people not involved in the conversation (this is a Q&A site, not a forum, though as mentioned we do have chat rooms which have a similar purpose).

Comment: It might be better if we did allow such things. It would add a lot of value to the site, but it might not be worth the consequences.

Comment: Ok Jonah I understand where you're coming from completely and I do apologise for the generality of the question on the whole,  More specificity from now on! Promise.

Comment: As you can see I took a shot at answering anyway.

Answer (score 6):

There are two *somewhat* objective answers to this question. What does the author think, and what is the character *like*?

### What did J.K. Rowling think?

In an [interview](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0700-hottype-solomon.htm), Rowling had this to say:

> E: Do you have more fun writing the evil characters? Because Voldemort
>   [the sinister wizard who killed Harry's parents] is the quintessential
>   evil character.
>
> JK: Yeah, he's a bad one. Do I have more fun? I loved writing
>   Dumbledore and Dumbledore is the epitome of goodness. But I loved
>   writing Gilderoy and I loved writing Rita. Because I just find them
>   comic characters.

So Rowling certainly *considers* Dumbledore good.

### What is Dumbledore like?

But is Dumbledore good? Like most things in fantasy, it depends on one's [point of view](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MetaphoricallyTrue?from=Main.FromACertainPointOfView).

Dumbledore is **secretive**. He rarely told the whole truth, even to those whom he cared about. As Aberforth says,

> “I knew my brother, Potter. He learned secrecy at our mother’s knee.
>   Secrets and lies, that’s how we grew up, and Albus. . . he was a
>   natural.”

He kept the truth about Horcruxes from Harry until Harry's sixth year. 
He gave Harry to relatives whom he may have known would conceal Harry's magical heritage from him. He never told Harry that he might have to sacrifice himself to ensure Voldemort's downfall; indeed, this last secret twice over.

Dumbledore is **manipulative**: he played on the feelings of others too achieve his goals, using Snape's love for Lily to turn him against Voldemort, or sending Harry to what could have been his death.

But Dumbledore is also **brave**: he has fought against dangerous Dark Wizards since his youth.

He is **self-sacrificial**: He is willing to (and indeed does) die to ensure Voldemort is no more. He uses his own blood, rather than Harry's, to open a pathway to Voldemort's sea cave.

He is **protective**: He wishes Snape to be the one to kill him, to spare an innocent the consequences to his soul. He has chosen to be Headmaster of Hogwarts, to protect the students there.

Dumbledore is in essence a highly **utilitarian** individual: he is willing to countenance ignoble deeds for the greater good. Never forget the cause of his youthful infatuation with Grindelwald:

> “Grindelwald. You cannot imagine how his ideas caught me, Harry, inflamed me. Muggles forced into subservience. We wizards triumphant.
>   Grindelwald and I, the glorious young leaders of the revolution.
>
> “Oh,
>   I had a few scruples. I assuaged my conscience with empty words. It
>   would all be for the greater good, and any harm done would be repaid a
>   hundredfold in benefits for wizards. Did I know, in my heart of
>   hearts, what Gellert Grindelwald was? I think I did, but I closed my
>   eyes. If the plans we were making came to fruition, all my dreams
>   would come true.

Gellert Grindelwald, of course, had no intention of working for the greater good at all. But it was arguably Dumbledore's attachment to that concept, along with his feelings toward Grindelwald, of course, that made this course of action so appealing to him. He shows the same sort of teleological ethics later in life.

Does this make him a good person? That, I think, is a matter of individual interpretation.